# Do I need preview for each device?

Tags: app-store-connect

I recently discovered how to upload preview videos of my app in use, I'm having some difficulty with some of the devices. If you decide to show a preview on one device, does it mean I must do the same for all other devices?

Comment: You may only submit a single set of app previews designed for iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad in one language localization. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/

Comment: @KosukeOgawa I understand that I'm limited to one video per device, but do I have to do a video for all of them?

Comment: You may introduce 0 or more preview videos, e.g. one for iPhone 4'' and one for iPad 1024x768. Preview videos do not work like a switch with all or nothing.